# Pass non-existing array element to function

Tags: php, arrays

I wish to use one function in PHP to get dynamic element value.

E.g. to replace lots of `echo isset($arrayFromDB['d']) ? $arrayFromDB['d'] : ''` to function call `echoEl($arrayFromDB['d'])`

Problem: how to pass array element that does not exist?

---

Theory algorithm, that will not work:

```
$arrayFromDB = ['a' => 'Aslovas', 'b' => 'Boslovas', 'c' => 'Coslovas'];

echoEl($arrayFromDB['d']); //Error will be here

private function echoEl($arrayElement) {
   if (isset($arrayElement)) { // Element is always set at this point
       echo $arrayElement;
   } else {
       echo '';
   }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve that variable checking function in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: this works for multidimensional arrays as well

```
function isSetOr(&$value, $default = null)
{
    return isset($value) ? $value : $default;
}
```

== EDIT ==
As pointed out below this will set non existing variables to null..
for your purpose you could use echo instead of return as well :)

```
function isSetOr(&$value, $default = null)
{
    echo isset($value) ? $value : $default;
}
```

Comment: +1 I didn't know passing a variable as reference would prevent `Notice: Undefined variable`

Comment: Note: After calling this function with an unset variable the variable (or array element) will exist and be set to Null! `isset` will still return false as it returns false on Null. (Try `function f(&$v){} $a=[]; f($a['key']); var_dump($a);`)

Comment: Good one, didn't think of that! :)

Comment: @johannes ah, so passing a non-existing variable as a reference just silently creates it and sets it to null then? Is this behaviour documented?

Comment: @KevinOpdenKamp ah, so passing a non-existing variable as a reference just silently creates it and sets it to null then? Is this behaviour documented?

Comment: It behaves as it should, it was something I just never thought of before. Passing something by reference means that whatever gets returned is gonna be the new value for whatever you pass in. Returning null means set the parameter passed by reference to null, effectively setting the possibly non-existing property. I can't think of any obvious drawbacks aside from some negligible ram usage.

Comment: @nl-x I assume it is documented in some way - but think about it: A reference is an alias. For having an alias to a thing you need a thing first. PHP creates things when needed. Calling a function using references accesses the variable in read-write mode, which doesn't emit the E_STRICT from read mode. My general advise: Don't use references in PHP. There is always(*) a better way. ( (*) There are two exceptions: one is when dealing with APIs which require references, i.e. `sort()`, second is highly optimized code for handling graphs or such but even then objects typically are more efficient)

Comment: @KevinOpdenKamp it already happens before the return... `function dump($arg){ var_dump($arg); } dump($nonExistant);` this outputs null, but does not yield any notice about undefined variables.

Comment: @johannes : all the documentation i can find is here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php It says: "*No other expressions should be passed by reference, as the result is undefined.*" ... I think this could qualify as a bug.

Comment: Ah there is a third case: bound variables and closures ... but only for trivial things like a counter, for more complex things an object is better ...

Comment: @nl-x no, that undefined behavior mostly refers to things you could do in older PHP versions where one could really mess with things. $foo['key'] qualifies as "variable" in that context ... and yes documentation isn't perfect there, but we try to discourage usage of references as much as possible

Comment: This is a famous video of me explaining some things about references: http://youtu.be/bxxIXPc9IR8 thoae are commonky quoted ted blog articles by me: http://schlueters.de/blog/index.php/archives/125-Do-not-use-PHP-references.html and http://schlueters.de/blog/index.php/archives/141-References-and-foreach.html (sorry - server issues break layout)

Comment: @johannes in my opinion, sending a non-existing variable should emit the same notice 'undefined variable' , regardless of whether it is being sent as a reference. Would not understand why not.

Comment: @nl-x The short version is: maybe, but the engine can't. The long version includes some assumptions made in the past which might be less valid than initially thought ... but then again: don't use references, avoid trouble.

Comment: Guys these comments are, although very interesting, outside the scope of the OP

Answer (score 0):

Currently in your `else` operator you have `echo '';` which does absolutely nothing so I haven't included it.

```
// array of data
$arrayFromDB = ['a' => 'Aslovas', 'b' => 'Boslovas', 'c' => 'Coslovas'];

// pass array and desired key to function
echoEl($arrayFromDB, 'd');

// function to print element if it exists
private function echoEl($array, $key) 
{
   if (isset($array[$key])) 
   {
       echo $array[$key];
   }
}
```

If you wanted this could be used in loops like this:

```
foreach ($arrayFromDB as $key => $value)
{
    echoEl($arrayFromDB, $key);
}
```

However there's not really much point as it's the equivalent to this:

```
foreach ($arrayFromDB as $value)
{
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: If it would be in loop, than there is no need to write function like that. But since it's in like 5 different pages where in single page can be more than 10 echoes, so it would be difficult to change something.

Comment: Yes you're completely right but I don't know how you're using this, so I gave a few examples.